# lua oop deep copy a table

Tags: recursion, lua, lua-table

My deep copy code:

```
function deepcopy(orig)
local orig_type = type(orig)
local copy
if orig_type == 'table' then
    copy = {}
    for orig_key, orig_value in next, orig, nil do
        copy[deepcopy(orig_key)] = deepcopy(orig_value)
    end
    setmetatable(copy, deepcopy(getmetatable(orig)))
else -- number, string, boolean, etc
    copy = orig
end
return copy
end
```

I'm trying to implement this to oop using `self`, but couldn't get it to work, here is what I've tried so far

```
function block:deepcopy()
local orig_type = type(self)
local copy
if orig_type == 'table' then
    copy = {}
   for orig_key, orig_value in next, self, nil do
       copy[self:deepcopy(orig_key)] = deepcopy(orig_value)
   end
   setmetatable(copy, self:deeepcopy(getmetatable(self)))
else
    copy = orig
end
return copy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OOP version of the function, `self:deepcopy(something)` with the method syntax (colon) doesn't do what you want it to. It is equivalent to `self.deepcopy(self, something)`; the second argument `something` is ignored and you just end up trying to re-copy the same `self` over and over until there's a stack overflow. You have to do `self.deepcopy(something)` with a dot to pass `something` as the `self` argument (the argument that is copied).

Calling `self.deepcopy` inside the definition of the `deepcopy` method assumes that every subtable has a `self.deepcopy` function. If not, you will get an "attempt to call a nil value" error. But you could do this if you want every subtable to have its own version of `deepcopy` that is used when copying the immediate children of that table (keys, values, metatable). For instance, you could have a subtable whose `deepcopy` method does not copy the metatable. Here is the basic version where the subtable has the same `deepcopy` method:

```
local block = {}

function block:deepcopy()
    if type(self) == 'table' then
        local copy = {}
        for key, value in pairs(self) do
            copy[self.deepcopy(key)] = self.deepcopy(value)
        end
        return setmetatable(copy, self.deepcopy(getmetatable(self)))
    else
        return self
    end
end

block.a = { a = 10, deepcopy = block.deepcopy }
block:deepcopy() -- works

block.a = { a = 10 }
block:deepcopy() -- error: "attempt to call a nil value (field 'deepcopy')"
```

But you don't need to rewrite the function at all to use it in object-oriented style. Try using your first definition of `deepcopy`. Do `object.deepcopy = deepcopy`, and then call `object:deepcopy()` and you will get a copy of the object.

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to automatically assign the function to values in the table?, I've tried adding `self.deepcopy = block.deepcopy` after the `if type(self) == 'table' then` line, doesnt seem to work, what I'm trying to achieve is to make an object has the ability to return the cloned version of itself